# What character does UITextField use for secureEntry?

Tags: iphone, ios, unicode, uitextfield

I'm attempting to mimic the look of a `UITextField` with secure entry, and I need to know what character it uses. I tried the unicode [bullet character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/browsertest.htm) "•" but it is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be the unicode [black circle](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/index.htm) "●".